# setting a reminder to a iphone calendar with xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, eventkit

I am trying to  add a reminder to an iphone with my app. I can add the reminder with an alarm that will ring at the specified time but it wont show up as a reminder in the phones pull down list like adding a reminder in siri does.
here is the code I have so far:

```
 public void AddReminder()
    {
        EKReminder reminder = EKReminder.Create(eventStore);

        reminder.Title = "Do something awesome!";
        // an error for the reminders and calendars
        NSError e = new NSError();
        // an alarm time
        EKAlarm timeToRing = new EKAlarm();
        timeToRing.AbsoluteDate = NSDate.Now.AddSeconds(61);

        reminder.AddAlarm(timeToRing);

        reminder.Notes = "do something noteworthy";

        //reminder.Calendar = calendar;
        reminder.Calendar = eventStore.DefaultCalendarForNewReminders;

        eventStore.SaveReminder(reminder, true, out e);

    }
```

I have a button the the main page of the form that will call this function. And I have all of the setup for the event store to get the permission and so forth.

Comment: Check what the value of `timeToRing.AbsoluteDate` is after you have set it and see it it corresponds with what you expect it to be. I know setting times for these things work a bit awkward sometimes. It might be in a different timezone or whatever when you set it.

Comment: I have tried doing that, but the alarm rings and pops up an alert at the correct time it just does not show in the reminders list of the phone.

Comment: @DavidEnglund - did you resolve this?  I have the same issue.  I can create the new list but cannot add a reminder, it returns **The operation couldn’t be completed. (EKCADErrorDomain error 1010.)**